# SchedulerException with Simple Job

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I'm trying to get started with Quartz.Net 2.0.  A very simple appearing test application is failing with a `SchedulerException`

> Trigger's related Job's name cannot be null

The code is adapted from the Version 2.0 [Migration Guide](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/migration_guide.html)

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler classSched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
classSched.Start();
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ClassificationJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("myJob", "My Group")
                    .WithDescription("My Description")
                    .Build();

TimeZoneInfo tzUtc = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
DateTime startTime;

startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "My Group")
    .WithDescription("My Description")
    .StartAt(startTime)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
    .Build();

classSched.ScheduleJob(trigger); // Exception on this line
```

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are two issues.

Firstly, (despite the example in the migration guide), I think that you need to say which job the trigger is related to, ie call the .ForJob method , for example

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "My Group")
    .WithDescription("My Description")
    .StartAt(startTime)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
    .ForJob(job)
    .Build();
```

Secondly, the syntax you are using to schedule the job only works if the job has previously been added (eg if you have previously called classSched.AddJob(job,true); // or classSched.AddJob(job,false);

If that hasn't already been done, then you need to use the syntax

```
  classSched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Doesn't requiring `ForJob(job)` belie the loose coupling between jobs and triggers that was an explicit design goal?  I'll give your suggestions a try in a few minutes.

Comment: You could be right, but in that case if you simply call `classSched.ScheduleJob(trigger);` Quartz would have no idea which job would want to run. Perhaps you only need to change your last line to `classSched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger); `

Comment: Turns out I only had to provide the `job` parameter to `ScheduleJob()`.